# XMP Image presets and conversions

Tags: python, camera, photo, preset

I handle a lot of my photos in bulk on a regular basis. I'm looking to apply a common XMP preset (developed in camera raw for cr2 files)

Originally I looked at using ap ython module to apply the preset, then convert the image from cr2 to jpeg with rawpy. This didn't work and a lot of the research I did pointed to the fact that these modules couldn't handle the xmp application within the module, due to complex lens corrections etc.

What I then thought was to look at the process manually, and it looked as though that when I applied these XMPs to the cr2 files, all that was happenign was that XMP file was being copied and renamed to suit the filename of the corresponding cr2(RAW) file.

So I thought why not write a code that copies that across for every file, then do the raw conversion once the XMP file was matched with the raw.

The previews after I run this code on the raw files work perfectly in bridge, so I can see that they're being copied and applied correctly to the cr2 file.

My question is, is there a way to have the cr2 file handled with these alterations on hand?

I wrote a sleep into the code to give it time to have the presets applied, per below

```
import os
import shutil
import PIL
import rawpy
import imageio
from PIL import Image
import time


xmp_preset = "path/to/PRESET.xmp"
raw_sorted = "path/to/RAW/"
jpg_output = "path/to/JPEG/"

for f in sorted(os.listdir(raw_sorted)):
    f_name,f_ext = (os.path.splitext(f))
    xmp_name01 = ('{}{}'.format(f_name,".xmp"))


    if os.path.exists(".DS_Store"):
        os.remove(".DS_Store")
    if os.path.exists("Thumbs.db"):
        os.remove("Thumbs.db")

    if f.endswith(".cr2"):
        shutil.copy(xmp_preset, raw_sorted)
        os.rename(raw_sorted + "PRESET.xmp", raw_sorted + xmp_name01)



time.sleep(10)

for f in os.listdir(raw_sorted):
    if f.endswith(".cr2"):
        f_name, f_ext = os.path.splitext(f)
        filepath = os.path.join(raw_sorted,f)
        jpegext = ".jpg"
        with rawpy.imread(filepath) as raw:
            rgb = raw.postprocess(use_camera_wb=True,gamma=None)
            path = os.path.join(jpg_output,f_name)
            newname = ("{}{}".format(path,jpegext))

            imageio.imwrite(newname,rgb)
```

The code works fine, it brings the XMP file across, renames it correctly and I can see that it has been applied, however, when the jpeg is output to the defined folder, it's done so as if the XMP was never a factor.

Is there a way to output the jpeg file using the applied XMP? I tried using rawpy parameters to try to get as close as possible to the desired look but it's just not right.

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the same thing

Comment: @AndrewPierno no - everything pointed to the modules not being able to handle the complex adobe corrections in the XMP. My workaround was to develop the presets i required and have them renamed to match the corresponding files depending on certain aspects of the file data, it will copy different presets for different files, then i just use the batch export preset in bridge to process all the files with the applied presets.